# Excel not properly comparing dates, despite same cell format

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I have two date rows. Both are formatted as dates. When I do a logic test to see whether the two dates, excel is not recognizing them as the same.

Here is a screenshot of the cells:

[image]

This is to confirm that both cell rows are formatted as date:
[image]

This is to confirm that the equality check row is referencing the right cells:

[image]

I'm stumped. Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? Thanks

Comment: What if you change the format to Number? Do both show the same number? What is the source of the data? Is there any leading space anywhere before the date in one of the cells? What if you try VALUE(TRIM(CellRef)) and make a compare? e.g. =VALUE(TRIM(G4))=VALUE(TRIM(G6))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dates are equal only if the **all portions** of it, including TIME VALUES embedded in the date, are equal.
I suggest to use `TEXT()` to compare only the date values. e.g:

`=TEXT(G4;"YYYY-MM-DD")=TEXT(G6;"YYYY-MM-DD")`

Note that the format codes to ACTUALLY use may be dependent on your locale (e.g. Swedes must use "ÅÅÅÅ" instead of "YYYY").

In your example; This `=(G4-INT(G4))<>(G6-INT(G6))` most likely yields TRUE
 *(comparing the decimal portions)*